# FOR /F not outputting correctly wen using move in the loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to clean up a few file shares, and I have the list of folders I'm trying to move in a CSV file.

values in delfromtest.csv
are

```
Test1
Test2
test3
```

I'm attempting to use this.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A IN (C:\delfromtest.csv) DO (
if EXIST %Drive%:\%%~A (set asset=%%~A%) 
move "%drive%:\images%drive%\%asset%" "%drive%:\images%drive%\Do not Migrate%drive%\%asset%"
)
```

this outputs

```
move "v:\imagesv\C:\delfromtest.csv" "v:\imagesv\Do not Migratev\C:\delfromtest.csv"
```

but if I remove the entire move command from the loop, the variables are output as desired.

Comment: that smells very much like the [delayed expanison trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) (`asset`). And there is a `%` too much. Should be: `(set asset=%%~A)` - except you want the `%` to be part of the value)

Answer (score 0):

try `for` without quotes or use [usebackq](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). Enable [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) when variable is set from and within `for`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (C:\delfromtest.csv) do ( set asset=%%~a
  if exist %Drive%:\!asset! (
    echo move "%drive%:\images%drive%\!asset!" "%drive%:\images%drive%\Do not Migrate%drive%\!asset!"
  )
)
exit /b 0
```

Comment: `echo move` should be just `move`, probably a leftover from testing. This comment is just a reminder, I'll remove it in a day.